# how to store a huge amount of data in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, arrays

I have to search over huge data from db through php code. I don't want to give many db hits. So i selected all data from db to be searched and tried to store it in array to do further search on array not on db, but problem is that the data exceeds the limit of array.
What to do?

Comment: SQL is tailored exactly to do searches. Can you be more precise about what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 19):

**Don't do that.**

Databases are designed specifically to handle large amounts of data. Arrays are not.

Your best bet would be to properly index your db, and then write your optimized query that will get the data you need from the database. You can use PHP to construct the query. You can get almost anything from a db through a good query, no need for PHP array processing.

If you gave a specific example, we could help you construct that SQL query.

Comment: I totally agree. In fact, yesterday I was asked by a colleague about traversing an array of data in PHP to search and extract rows in a certain sorted way. I told him: "why don't you order by xxx?", "why don't you use a view?", "why don't you..". After minutes of conversation we agreed that the data model needed to be redesigned lol

Answer (score 4):

Databases are there to filter the data for you. Use the most accurate query you can, and only filter in code if it's too hard (or impossible) to do in SQL.

A full table selection can be much more expensive (especially for I/O on the db server, and it can have dire effects on the server's cache) than a correctly indexed `select` with the appropriate `where` clause(s).

Answer (score 2):

There is communication overhead involved when obtaining records from a database to PHP, so not only is it a good idea to reduce the number of calls from PHP to the database, but it is also ideal to minimize the number of elements returned by the database and processed in your PHP code. You should structure your query (depending on the type of database) to return just the entries you need or as few entries as possible for whatever you need to do. There are a lot of databases that support fairly complex operations directly within the database query, and typically the database will do it way faster than PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Two simple steps:

1. Increase the amount of memory php can use via the memory_limit setting
2. Install more RAM

Seriously, you'll be better off optimizing your database in a way that you can quickly pull the data you need to work on.

If you are actually running into problems, then run a query analyzer to see which queries are taking too much time. Fix them. Repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need to store your data in an array, it makes no sense.  Structure your query accordingly your purpose and then fetch the data with PHP.
2. In case, if you need to increase your memory limit you can change `memory_limit` in php.ini (or update .htaccess with desired memory limit `php_value memory_limit '1024M'`)
3. Last but not least - use a pagination, rather than load the whole data at once.